# Button not clickable when added to listview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-button

i have this layout, but the button is not clickable.
i tried solutions from previous posts, such as adding `android:focusable="false"` to the button or listview or the linear layout but it didnt work. i tried adding : `button.setFocusable(false)` after the button `OnClickListener` but also didnt work. i even tried adding: `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` to the main linear layout but the problem still exists.
Thanks.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/search_field"
        android:layout_width="181dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.25"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Search"
        android:textColor="#1F6260" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/refresh_button"
        android:layout_width="34dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:background="@drawable/refresh3" />
</LinearLayout>
<ListView
  android:id="@+id/list2"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:divider="#b5b5b5"
  android:dividerHeight="1dp"
  android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector">
</ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Java code:

```
refresh= (Button)myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.refresh_button);
refresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ((MainTabs)getActivity()).refresh();
            ((MainTabs)getActivity()).getUsersList();
        }
    });
```

Added the toast in the onclick method and it showed, so my code isn't working and nothing is wrong with the button. Sorry for this inconvenience. 
Thanks.

Comment: Did you forget to close the first `LinearLayout` tag?

Comment: I just forgot to add it in this post.

Comment: what do you mean by "not clickable" ?

Comment: @Krishna it doesnt respond to a click.

Comment: If background image is used in a button, it has no clicking visual effect

Comment: can u post java code ?

Comment: @Krishna True, but the code in the`refresh.setOnClickListener()` is not being executed.

Comment: can u place a toast inside the onclick method

Comment: added the toast and it showed. So my code has some problems and not the button. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways to achieve this

1.

Change your button like this

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/refresh_button"
        android:layout_width="34dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:background="@drawable/refresh3"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="buttonClick" />
```

then create a method inside your activity which have to pass your View as parameter like this.

```
public void buttonClick(View v) {}
```

or you can follow the second way

2.

```
        Button button;
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.refresh_button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: thanks for your reply. turned out that the problem is in my code written under the onclick method.